# How to retrieve individual controls from a wxFrame in wxPHP?

Tags: php, wxphp

I'm loading wxWidgets assets in a PHP program using `wxXmlResource()`. This loads the window very well, but I am not sure how to get an object reference to named window elements.

Here is my code:

```
// Load the window
$resource = new wxXmlResource();
$resource->InitAllHandlers();
$resource->Load(__DIR__ . '/forms.xrc.xml');

// Get a reference to a window
$frame = new wxFrame();
$resource->LoadFrame($frame, NULL, 'frmOne');
$frame->Show();

// Fetch a named element - the class returned is the base class
$textCtrl = $frame->FindWindow('m_staticText12');
echo get_class($textCtrl) . "\n";
```

The `$textCtrl` item should be a `wxStaticText` object but it has been returned as a `wxWindow` (which is a parent class). Since it is not cast as the correct object type, I can't call methods belonging to the control's own class (such as `Wrap()`).

I think the `FindWindow()` call is working, since if I get the name deliberately wrong, it returns `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the wxDynamicCast function to cast object to proper type like:

```php
$textCtrl = wxDynamicCast(
    $frame->FindWindow('m_staticText12'), 
    "wxStaticText"
);
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I will try that and if it works send you another PR - this time a simple demo for `wxXmlResource`. Incidentally this seems like a good way to create frame assets - GTK doesn't emit any warnings at all.

Comment: I've tried this and can confirm this works. Is this approach universal for all wxWidgets wrappers (e.g. wxPython), do you know? It seems rather unexpected for `FindWindow()` to return the base class and not an instance-specific type.

Comment: Since C++ isn't a dynamic language all that FindWindow() could return is a void* or a parent class pointer from which all child's inherit. In this case, since wxWindow inherits from wxObject, it should be possible to determine the object type by using wxObject methods.

Comment: Alright, a C++ limitation - fair enough. Thank you again!